# How can I make C++0x and __STRICT_ANSI__ get along?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, mingw, gnu

I need to use `popen` in a project, but I get:

```
error: 'popen' was not declared in this scope
```

It looks like GCC defines `__STRICT_ANSI__` under both `-std=c++0x` and (contrary to what little information I was able to find) `-std=gnu++0x`, which causes `popen` (and `_popen`) to be elided from `stdio`. Oddly enough, undefining `__STRICT_ANSI__` doesn't solve the issue, nor does forward-declaring the function. I'm obviously missing something. Is there a reasonable workaround?

I was using MinGW with 4.5.0, and upgraded to 4.5.2, but am still experiencing the same problem. I'd rather not have to muck about with msys to compile 4.6.0, but I will if I must.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm simply undefining it on the commandline right away, this is not terribly "clean" but it works fine from what I can tell.

```
-std=gnu++0x -U__STRICT_ANSI__
```

There is probably a good reason why one should not do that, but it gives me what I want (C++0x plus GNU extensions, plus legacy stuff still works). I've been doing this for a long time and never run into trouble. But don't blame me if it eats your cat.

Comment: Whaddaya know, that does it. I actually had some conflicting settings elsewhere in my environment that were causing mischief.

Comment: Yeah, been there before... totally annoying. Easiest thing I found to save pain was to simply add the above to the IDE's global compiler options. Admittedly, it's not the prettiest thing on earth, but I've never had a build (neither my own, nor third party stuff) fail again due to this problem thereafter.

Comment: +1 Same thing with gcc 4.5.3 under Cygwin. Alas, with `__STRICT_ANSI__` vital functions like `vsnprintf` are not defined. Obviously, the gcc maintainers do not compile their test suite with all possible `-std=xxx`'s, as it ought to be.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler: This is not a GCC problem but headers problem, I think. Cygwin headers defining `vsnprintf()` are not coming from GCC.

Comment: @Damon: Could you show how to use this method ? I want to install **ACADOtoolkit**, which an optimization package, which after `cmake ..` and then subsequently on `make` gives me this error (popen ...). I tried adding the flags you showed to the make command, but it doesnt'w work that way. How and where do I add the line ?

Comment: @ChintanPathak: Not using cmake if I can avoid doing so, since I loathe it -- so, I'm not precisely an expert on that one! But I guess something like `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -U__STRICT_ANSI__")` inside `CMakeLists.txt` will do. Not sure if cmake respects environment variables like `CFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS`, if that is the case you could just set that one prior to invoking it, too.

Answer (score 9):

I tested both MinGW gcc 4.6.1 and gcc 4.7.0: They both do define `__STRICT_ANSI__` for `-std=c++0x`, but do not define it for `-std=gnu++0x`.

Comment: The same holds for `c++11` and `gnu++11` if anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer to the question

> How can I make C++0x and __STRICT_ANSI__ get along?

should be: use `-std=gnu++0x` instead of `-std=c++0x`. This should *not* define `__STRICT_ANSI__` **[1]**, so there's probably something else in you `Makefile` or build environment that still causes this to be defined **[2]**.

A (less-prefered) work-around then, as pointed out by others, would be to un-define it with a command-line switch `-U__STRICT_ANSI__`.

Note that for specifying which C standard your code is written for, `-std=gnu++*` would be the typical switch to use, rather than `-std=c++*`, as long as you want the GNU extensions (in `gcc`, the GNU extensions are enabled by default, but will be disabled if you specify `-std=c++*`).

Another note; for C, this is similar:

```
$ touch empty.c
$ gcc -std=c99 -E -dM empty.c | grep '\(__STRICT\|__STDC_V\)'
#define __STRICT_ANSI__ 1
#define __STDC_VERSION__ 199901L
$ gcc -std=gnu99 -E -dM empty.c | grep '\(__STRICT\|__STDC_V\)'
#define __STDC_VERSION__ 199901L
```

You'll get language support for the desired C version, with or without `__STRICT_ANSI__` defined (there are possibly other differences as well).

---

**[1]:**

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html:

> __STRICT_ANSI__
>
> GCC defines this macro **if and only if the -ansi switch, or a -std switch specifying strict conformance to some version of ISO C or ISO C++**, was specified when GCC was invoked. It is defined to ‘1’. This macro exists primarily to direct GNU libc's header files to restrict their definitions to the minimal set found in the 1989 C standard.

That this is the case can easily be confirmed (run on `gcc` 4.8.2):

```
$ touch empty.cpp
$ gcc -std=c++0x -E -dM empty.cpp | grep '__STRICT'
#define __STRICT_ANSI__ 1
$ gcc -std=gnu++0x -E -dM empty.cpp | grep '__STRICT'
$ # (no match)
```

**[2]:** Something adding an `-ansi` switch perhaps? This will yield the `__STRICT_ANSI__`, even if specifying `-std=gnu++*`, as is stated by the documentation (see citation above), and can easily be checked:

```
$ gcc -std=gnu++0x -E -dM -ansi empty.cpp | grep '__STRICT'
#define __STRICT_ANSI__ 1
```