# Why is Xcode 4.2 applying C files build rule script for .cpp files?

Tags: c++, xcode4.2

I have an Xcode 4.2 project which includes a target that cross-compiles for windows. I use custom build rules for C source files and C++ source files in that target, invoking i386-pc-mingw32-g++ via a custom script. For some reason, Xcode runs the custom script I have specified as being for C source files, even when compiling files with a .cpp extension. Why might this be? How can I get Xcode 4.2 to run the "C++ source files" script for my .cpp files?

I also have .c files in this project, and am hoping to use -std=c++11 flag when compiling c++ files to enable some c++11 features. If I compile the .c files with this flag, I end up with weird scoping issues on constants included from math.h that I have yet to really try and understand - I am hoping I can just get Xcode to run the correct script for my .cpp files.

Any ideas?

Update: I've been able to get Xcode to run the correct scripts. To do this, I had to change the Process drop-down menu selections from "C source files" and "C++ source files" both to "Source files with names matching:" and then manually enter `*.c` and `*.cpp` in the provided text field. Now I have to figure out why I'm getting an `M_PI was not declared in this scope` error message where I wasn't before - maybe a different version of math.h is being used with the -std=c++11 flag which either doesn't include the M_PI constant or provides it under a different namespace?

Update: Continuing to work on this - it appears the M_PI value I was using from math.h is actually a macro which is only #define'd if `__STRICT_ANSI__` has not been defined. Apparently switching to c++11 by using the -std=c++11 compiler flag has caused this `__STRICT_ANSI__` macro to be defined, and thus the M_PI macro I was previously using isn't there. I suppose it's better to just define my own pi constants than to mess with the declaration of this `__STRICT_ANSI__` macro, but I'll probably dig into that a bit just to clarify why it is being declared now that I'm using the c++11 flag.

Update: I found this post [How can I make C++0x and __STRICT_ANSI__ get along?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580921/how-can-i-make-c0x-and-strict-ansi-get-along), which just suggests undefining the '**STRICT_ANSI**' macro right after the '-std=c++11' flag (or rather, the equivalent '-std=c++0x' flag. While this seems sketchy, no one has posted encountering any problems because of it and it appears to work just fine for me as well in this case. Gcc documentation on this macro is located here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html, with the following relevant statement:

> The macro **STRICT_ANSI** is predefined when the -ansi option is used. Some header files may notice this macro and refrain from declaring certain functions or defining certain macros that the ISO standard doesn't call for; this is to avoid interfering with any programs that might use these names for other things.

Still not sure why the '-std=c++11' flag causes this to be defined when it isn't by default (which would be '-std=c++98', apparently).

Comment: Not positive, but my guess is that Xcode prefers `*.cxx` naming convention.

Comment: The funny thing is that if you hover your mouse over the "C source files" and "C++ source files" entries in the list, you get a little tooltip that says `sourcecode.c` and `sourcecode.cpp`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you want C++11 support without ANSI mode, use `-std=gnu++11` instead of `std=c++11`.

Comment: Are there any major differences between these two that I should be aware of?

Comment: @thamoonisdown: `std=gnu++11` enables GCC extensions to the compiler and libraries. `std=c++11` follows the Standard as closely as possible by disabling extensions.  `STRICT_ANSI` you get by disabling extensions.  In your question you mentioned `std=c++03`.  That is not the default, and it would enable `STRICT_ANSI`.  The default is `std=gnu++03` (your link shows this).  If you were happy with handling of `M_PI` under the default, then `std=gnu++11` is the right way to simply add C++11 support.

Comment: Whoops, I guess I misread the default. Thanks for this clarification.